# How to skip visual mode on bash prompt when returning from visual mode editing?

Tags: bash, vim, terminal

I'm a pretty active vim user so I like to have the vi mode active on the bash line.  For the most part, I don't feel the need to slip into the full visual editor for entering commands, but sometimes it can be kind of useful.

Whenever I do though, I always end up forgetting that when you quit the editor you're still in command mode, not insert mode.  To me this seems totally silly since it returns you to an empty prompt, so you can expect to start typing.  Half the time I go to start typing "vim" and then end up re-entering a vim editor for my command line.

Is there a way to make returning to insert mode the default for bash?

Comment: How are you enabling `vi` mode? `set -o vi` appears to put me in insert mode by default.